# Remote link in dropdown menu prevent menu toggling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a rails app, I'm using Bootstrap 3 and its dropdown menus.

When I'm using remote link inside, after the ajax call the dropdown doesn't toggle as a normal link, it just stay open. Here is the markup :

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Moderation<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="test" data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/admin/entries/1/accept" rel="nofollow">Accept</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="test" data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/admin/entries/1/refuse" rel="nofollow">Refuse</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I suspect that it's related to how event are caught in rails ujs but I'm not a javascript expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to make it work (not sure it's the better way,  comments are welcome)

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu a[data-remote=true]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('ul').prev('button').dropdown('toggle');
    });
});
```